# ERROR [XulParser] handler not found: W?NDOW

Tags: java, startup, pentaho

PDI(spoon.bat) crashes on startup. Here's /logs/spoon.log:

```
09:59:04,793 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
09:59:08,932 INFO  [KarafInstance] 
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 1 at f:\user\pdi-ce-8.0.0.0-28\data-integration\ ***
***   .\system\karaf\caches\spoon\data-1                                    ***
*** FastBin Provider Port:52901                                             ***
*** Karaf Port:8802                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9051                                                  ***
*******************************************************************************
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:09 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
2018-02-20 09:59:14.928:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.15.v20140411
2018-02-20 09:59:15.055:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started NIOSocketConnectorWrapper@0.0.0.0:9051
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/parameterized-types
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-management (171) [org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-wsdl (174) [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-xml (176) [org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory, org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.wsdl11.XMLWSDLExtensionLoader]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap (177) [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/bindings/soap
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-policy (195) [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine, org.apache.cxf.policy.PolicyDataEngine, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyAnnotationListener, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.DomainExpressionBuilderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.EndpointReferenceDomainExpressionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.URIDomainExpressionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMPolicyInterceptorProvider]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http (178) [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/simple
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws (180) [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs-client
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/binding/coloc
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-local (191) [org.apache.cxf.transport.local.LocalTransportFactory]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-object (192) [org.apache.cxf.binding.object.ObjectBindingFactory]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/binding/object
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/policy
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-addr (212) [org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.AddressingWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.WSAddressingFeature$WSAddressingFeatureApplier, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MAPAggregator$MAPAggregatorLoader]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-security (214) [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader, org.apache.cxf.ws.security.cache.CacheCleanupListener]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-rm (216) [org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMManager, org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.RMPolicyInterceptorProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.RM10AssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.RM12AssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.WSRMP12PolicyLoader, org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.MC11PolicyLoader, org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.RSPPolicyLoader]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/ws/rm/manager
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFO: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:16 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-javascript (217) [org.apache.cxf.javascript.JavascriptServerListener]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:17 AM org.pentaho.caching.impl.PentahoCacheManagerFactory$RegistrationHandler$1 onSuccess
INFO: New Caching Service registered
09:59:17,972 ERROR [KarafCapabilityProvider] No feature found matching id: common-ui-client-config
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/F:/user/pdi-ce-8.0.0.0-28/data-integration/launcher/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/f:/user/pdi-ce-8.0.0.0-28/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:20 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /lineage
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:20 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /i18n
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:21 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /marketplace
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:22 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /repositories
?ub 20, 2018 9:59:24 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /browser
09:59:30,154 ERROR [XulParser] handler not found: W?NDOW
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Error initializing transformation
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.ui.xul.XulException: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulLoader.loadXul(AbstractXulLoader.java:134)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.SwtXulLoader.loadXul(SwtXulLoader.java:128)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.SwtXulLoader.loadXul(SwtXulLoader.java:122)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulLoader.loadXul(AbstractXulLoader.java:238)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.init(Spoon.java:850)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createContents(Spoon.java:9209)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:785)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9240)a
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.XulParser.parseDocument(XulParser.java:92)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulLoader.loadXul(AbstractXulLoader.java:126)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     ... 14 more
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : Error starting Spoon shell
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.init(Spoon.java:903)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createContents(Spoon.java:9209)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:785)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9240)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018/02/20 09:59:30 - General -     at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
stopping
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue configuring the spoon.bat by adding:

```
"-Duser.country=US" "-Duser.language=en"
```

inline before  `"-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` to have:

```
...
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-Duser.country=US" "-Duser.language=en" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
...
```

Based on the issue [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/180043-Pentaho-never-launches-and-gives-a-xul-exception).